# Avro schema deserialisation in Flink Table API

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to consume some data from Kafka with Flink. Topics with Confluent Avro schema work fine. But with embedded schema getting error.

Seems like its having problems to deserialize those Avro messages. Any idea how to troubleshoot further?

```
tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE table (\n" +
                "  `field` STRING\n" +
                ") WITH (\n" +
                "  'connector' = 'kafka',\n" +
                "  'topic' = 'dat.topic',\n" +
                "  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '" + brokers + "',\n" +
                "  'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup3',\n" +
                "  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',\n" +
                "  'format' = 'avro',\n" +
                "  'properties.security.protocol' = 'SSL',\n" +
                "  'properties.ssl.key.password' = '" + keyPassword+ "',\n" +
                "  'properties.ssl.keystore.location' = \'" + keyStoreLocation + "\',\n" +
                "  'properties.ssl.keystore.password' = '" + keyPassword+ "',\n" +
                "  'properties.ssl.truststore.location' = \'" + trustStoreLocation + "\',\n" +
                "  'properties.ssl.truststore.password' = '" + keyPassword+ "'\n" +
                ")");

        Table table2 = tEnv.from("table");
        table2.limit(10).execute().print();


Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize consumer record ConsumerRecord(topic = dat.topic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 0, CreateTime = 169392, serialized key size = 24, serialized value size = 27836, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = RaType, value = [76]), RecordHeader(key = kafkaSerializationType, value = [65, 86, 82, 79])], isReadOnly = false), key = [C@56dcb40d, value = [C@04f4fc48).
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.deserializer.KafkaDeserializationSchemaWrapper.deserialize(KafkaDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:57)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter.emitRecord(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:53)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize Avro record.
```

Comment: How was the data produced?